# Set referer on first visit to site

Tags: php, referrer

I have a site where the phone number in the header file needs to change depending on the referrer. If someone comes to the site via google, for example, the phone number is different that if they came directly to the site.
I have it working, except for when the user goes to a different page on the site. The code checks the referrer and changes the number to the direct number.
What I want is for the number to be set by the referrer the first time the user visits the site, and for it not to change. I imagine cookies or sessions are the way to go here, I"m just not sure how the code should be structured.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) //user has come via search engine or a page within our site
{
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($referer,'google') !== false) {
$callin_number='1-444-444-4444';
$callin_dialer=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $callin_number);
}   
elseif (strpos($referer,'bing') !== false) {
$callin_number='1-111-111-1111';
$callin_dialer=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $callin_number);
}
else {
$callin_number='1-222-222-2222';
$callin_dialer=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $callin_number);
}
}

else { //user has come directly to site
$callin_number='1-333-333-3333';
$callin_dialer=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $callin_number);
}
```

Comment: simple. store the number in the session. if the value in the session is empty, it's never been set and you run the above code. then you just keep pulling the same stored value out.

Comment: I suggest writing a record to the database that contains the immediate referal.  Then just call that up every time the user goes to another page.

Comment: Sessions are a bad idea because the user will see different numbers after likely a short while. Use a long term cookie to identify the visitor, relating that to visitor data in your database. Create a visitor record if the cookie isn't set. Load the visitor data on each page request. Display the desired number accordingly.

Comment: "I imagine cookies or sessions are the way to go here" Have you done any research into how to use these? Have you made any attempt? That'd be where to start.

Comment: Patrick, yes; I should add I'm using WordPress and getting errors now:
Notice: Undefined index: callin_number in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php on line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use session or cookie:

semi-pseudo:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ( !isset( $_SESSION['referer'] ) )
{

   put your code here, and put whatever you need to session:

   $_SESSION['referer'] = ...
   $_SESSION['dialin'] = ....

}
```

and use `$_SESSION['referer etc']` in your code instead of `$referer etc`.

`$_SESSION['referer etc']` will be available on the next page load,
    the IF condition above will be false on the next page load.

Cookies are just a bit different: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Thanks rlatief; I got it to work. Checking to see if the session was already started was the key.